# IFNULL on DATETIME doesn't work with comparisons

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-date-functions

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    colA DATETIME,
    colB DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO test (colA, colB) VALUES ('2017-01-01', NULL);
```

Here's some SQL I'm trying to run on this schema:

```
SELECT
    colA < IFNULL(colB, '9999-99-99') AS a,
    colA < '9999-99-99' AS b,
    IFNULL(colB, '9999-99-99') AS c
FROM test;
```

My question is...  why is `a`, in the SELECT results, 0 when `b` is 1? 2017-01-01 is less than 9999-99-99...

And given that `a` is 0...  what can I do to make it so that it is 1? ie. so that the date on the right hand side of the comparison operator is /always/ set to the latest possible date (so that no date falls after it..)

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82fe8d/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that `9999-99-99` is not a valid date, you can change it to `9999-12-31`.  This produces more sensible results.  As to why `b` in your query gets a `1`... I see that it does in the fiddle, but I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

A date compared to a non-date is not more or less

The following query will work as expected

```
SELECT 
    colA < IFNULL(colB, '2017-01-02') AS a,
    colA < '2017-01-02' AS b,
    IFNULL(colB, '2017-01-02') AS c
FROM test;
```

You can also try this to see what I mean:

```
SELECT
    colA < IFNULL(colB, CAST('9999-99-99' AS DATETIME)) AS a,
    colA < CAST('9999-99-99' AS DATETIME) AS b,
    IFNULL(colB, '9999-99-99') AS c
FROM test;
```